Leagcy code with structs, how to do implicit conversion
I have C legacy code with structs. It looks like this:
typedef struct data
{
    int a;
} data;

typedef struct user
{
    data d;
} user;

data* get(user* u){return &u->d};

Now I want to extend data without touching it. For that, I introduced a new struct:
typedef struct newDataType
{
    int a;
    int b;
} newDataType;

typedef struct user
{
    newDataType d;
} data;

Is there a way to do to do a conversion so that get() can be used without changing it:
data* d1 = get(u);
newDataType* d2 = get(u);

With this testcode I get return': cannot convert from 'newDataType *' to 'data *':
void func()
{
    user u;
    
    data* d1 = get(&u);
    newDataType* d2 = get(&u);
}

I can change user and newDataType.

without changing it: without changing get? What can we change? I do not follow, it is function get, and struct user is redefined. You want just #define get(u)  (&u->d)?

Yes, sorry, will edit question

Either way I don't see the problem.

Your example looks quite simplified. It shows very simple data structures, whereas real code often has structures with more members and more varied types. This difference is important. If the parameter to get is a pointer to some structure and you want to use it with a pointer to a structure to some fundamentally different structure, then the task is impossible:…

A pointer gives an address in memory where there is data laid out in some specific way particular to the structure members and their types, and there is no way to convert this to a pointer to the old structure type because there is no place in memory where the data is laid out in the way of the old structure. No conversion is possible because there is no address the conversion can produce that would be an address where data is laid out in the way of the old structure…

… Now, it may be that you have some particular situation where a kludge can be applied or a situation where some intervention can solve the problem. For example, if the old structure is a subset of the new structure such that the old structure layout in memory is a prefix of the new structure layout, and you are willing to rely in implementation-dependent properties regarding this, then a forced conversion may be possible. Or, if you are willing to interpose a new “get” routine that takes the new structure type, allocates memory, copies data from the new structure to the…

… old structure to create an instance of the old structure type, passes that memory to get, remembers the return value of get, releases the temporary memory, and returns the return value of get, then that may be a possible solution. However, for advice to be written on any of these, you need to clarify the problem and its constraints.

I think there is a typo at the end of: typedef struct user { newDataType d; } data;.

The inheritance in C is usually done the same way as in C++. Just a little less control over it from compiler:
typedef struct {
   int a;
} data;

typedef struct {
   data d;
   int b;
} newData;

typedef struct
{
    newData nd;
} user;

// And you now have an old structure available for work as it was
data* get(user* u){ return &u->nd.d; }

// The next two functions are equivalent.
// Just ensure that inherited member is a first one. 
data* get(user* u){return (data*)&u};
data* get(user* u){return (data*)&u->nd};

If you do not want (or unable) to change get() function, you can change the data struct.
If both data and get() are locked for you, but you still want to expand user structure, then do just that:
typedef struct
{
    data d;
    newData nd;
} user;

